# Sims 3 isn't working

Tags: origin, the-sims-3

My friend was playing The Sims 3 just fine, but I downloaded Origin on her computer, and now The Sims 3 and its expansions will not work.

We would click on the logo, and the game would try to start, but would end up glitching out. What should we do?

My friend has a product key, but was not required to set up Origin, in order to play.

Comment: Off memory, sims 3 requires origin. Does your friend have a product key or was the game downloaded?

Comment: Product key I think she

Comment: Turns out you can play without origin, so we will assume your friend has an early-edition key. Unfortunately, a key is used to identify legitimate copies. Even if your friend is not using a pirated version, there is likely to be no legitimate way to get around not having a key.

Comment: So can she just not play her game or...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that your friend was playing The Sims 3 prior to the installation of Origin suggests your friend has a copy that predates the updates that require Origin. [A post at Answers.EA](http://answers.ea.com/t5/The-Sims-3/Does-the-Sims-3-require-origin-to-play/td-p/543698) suggests that you require Origin at version 1.42, which was released in late 2012. The same user also reports that this should never be an issue when only using discs as a source of game updates.

It is quite obvious that Origin is causing the problem. With the information you have provided, it is hard to tell whether Origin has tried to update the game, or if it is automatically attempting to validate it. However, there should be two easy solutions to fix both problems.

### Solution One: Delete Origin.

As it appears that early copies of The Sims 3 do not require Origin, and your friend was successfully playing The Sims 3 prior to its installation, it is easy to assume that deleting Origin will solve the problem. Unfortunately, there is the possibility that Origin has already updated The Sims 3 to the point where it requires Origin. If you come to this conclusion, either reinstall The Sims 3 from scratch, or continue on to solution two.

### Solution Two: Link The Sims 3 with your Origin account.

Alternatively, you could simply set up The Sims 3 to run through Origin. This will not prevent you from performing a fresh install with your available discs, and running as you had, previously.

You should be able to link The Sims 3 to Origin by [registering The Sims 3 with a valid EA Account](https://steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/?url=https://activate.ea.com/activategame.do), using your CD key. Ensure that your EA account is the same email used to access Origin, as users report that Origin should pick up on the access immediately.

Comment: How do u delete origin

Comment: @Naomi Boenrer, not a problem. Just make sure you accept the answer, if it all works like before, so others know it worked :)